# How to increase false positives and reduce false negatives in a logistic regression?

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

The results I am getting in a record linkage problem is classifying more values as false positives than false negatives. Is there a way to balance these?

```
# Initialize the classifier

    logreg = rl.LogisticRegressionClassifier()

# Train the classifier

    logreg.fit(golden_pairs, golden_matches_index)
    print ("Intercept: ", logreg.intercept)
    print ("Coefficients: ", logreg.coefficients)

# Predict the match status for all record pairs
result_logreg = logreg.predict(test_pairs[columns_to_keep])

len(result_logreg)

#true_links = features_complete_new_index[features_complete_new_index['evaluation'] == True].index
true_links = test_pairs[test_pairs['evaluation'] == True].index


print("confusion matrix of Logistic Regression ",rl.confusion_matrix(true_links, result_logreg, len(test_pairs)), "False positives ", rl.false_positives(true_links, result_logreg), "False negatives ", rl.false_negatives(true_links, result_logreg))


The output is Intercept:  -6.974042394356818
Coefficients:  [-0.07818545  7.83113994  0.96939354 -6.97404239  1.65737031  0.694744  ]
confusion matrix of Logistic Regression  [[   5915    2576]
 [   1075 7167134]] False positives  1075 False negatives  2576
F-Score of Log Regr  0.7641625218009173
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot simply tell you what is wrong with your implementation. There are a myriad of things that it could be: How clean and sanitized is your data, have you done any feature engineering, are you using cross fold validation, have you tried SFS or BFE, etc. Please try to rework your question to be a bit more direct so we can help you.

Comment: did you try to resample?  [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html]

Comment: It would help if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

you can always adjust your classifier, but what do you mean by balanced? With FP and FN it is more interessting, what prediction hurts you more?

A FN (False negativ) prediction is a prediction with is original a True prediction and was not recognized with your classifier. So if you try to detect fraud detection, and your True values are fraud, then a false negative would be a real problem, as this fraud would not have been recognized.

This is a book full of answers, we could tell you about. Try to adjust this line of code: `logreg = rl.LogisticRegressionClassifier()`and see how it changes

Comment: It would help if you explained _how_ to change that particular line of code.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html this is your playsheet, for example you can set `logreg= rl.LogisticRegressionClassifier(penalty=’l1’)`

Comment: Where did you find that OP uses a scikitlearn implementation? The scikitlearn logistic regression is called 'LogisticRegression', so your example seems invalid and inconsistent with the link you provide.